# What different multisig contracts are supported by `tezos-client`?

Tags: smart-contracts, tezos-client, multisig

What are the different multisig contracts are currently supported by `tezos-client` and which ones are planned to be supported? What is the difference between them and their respective hashes? Which ones have been formally verified?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the detailed history of the multisig contract supported in
`tezos-client`:

## Basic multisig, with replay attack

Hash `475e37a6386d0b85890eb446db1faad67f85fc814724ad07473cac8c0a124b31`.

The first basic multisig supported by `tezos-client`.

This version supports:

- single transfers
- updating the delegate
- updating keys and threshold
  All transfers of funds to the contract require a
  multisigned-authentication.

This version should not be used anymore because it is subject to a
small replay attack: when the test chain is forked both instances have
the same address and counter so whatever happens on the test chain can
be replayed on the main chain.

## Patched basic multisig

Hash `36cf0b376c2d0e21f0ed42b2974fedaafdcafb9b7f8eb9254ef811b37cb46d94`.

To fix the issue in the previous version of Basic multisig, the
`CHAIN_ID` Michelson instruction was added in Babylon and the contract
was rewritten at Babylon activation (by rewriting the chain history:
this is called stitching) with this new instruction.

This version has been verified using Mi-Cho-Coq [here](https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/mi-cho-coq/-/blob/master/src/contracts/arthur/multisig.tz).

## Patched basic multisig, new DIIP macro definition

Hash `a59ea55f38e1bcdde29e72a7f3608faf4314165d07083383efadfcf023e4c1e2`

If you originate the Patched basic multisig now you will get a
different hash because the `DIIP {code}` macro has changed (from `DIP {DIP {code}}` to `DIP 2 {code}`).

## Forthcoming: Generic multisig

Work is ongoing (in [!1857](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/merge_requests/1857)) to add support
in `tezos-client` for the [generic multisig contract](https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/mi-cho-coq/-/blob/master/src/contracts_coq/multisig.v).

In this new version:

- transfers can be batched
- transfers can contain parameters
- sending funds to the contract does not require multi-signed authentication anymore

This version has been verified using Mi-Cho-Coq [here](https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/mi-cho-coq/-/blob/master/src/contracts/arthur/generic_multisig.tz).

When released, the only reason to prefer the basic multisig contract
over the generic one is that it is currently the only one supported by
`tezos-client`. Once the generic version is fully supported by the
client, I don't think it will make sense to use the client to
originate new instances of the basic contract so this functionality
will be dropped. Interacting with instances of previous versions that
are already on the chain should however continue to work.

## Acknowledgements

This answer is largely sourced from Raphaël's comment [here](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/863#note_376456995).